# Time multiple commands running in parallel in shell and save it in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, time

I have a bash script for which i want to know the time it took to run for individual commands and save them in a log file. Also I need some of these commands to run as a different process. The problem I am facing is I am not able to tell which output belongs to which command  for example my script has:

```
echo "output 1:"
(time my_commnad1) 2>> my_log_file.log &

echo "output 2:"
(time my_commnad2) 2>> my_log_file.log &


echo "output 3:"
(time my_commnad3) 2>> my_log_file.log &

echo "output 4:"
(time my_commnad4) 2>> my_log_file.log &
wait
```

desired output(note here I can see which output belongs to which command ):

```
output 1:
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

output 2:
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

output 3:
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

output 4:
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
```

but i get something like:

```
output1:
output2
output3:
output4:
```

(not sure if they are in order cant tell which one is which), Here I am not sure which output belongs to which command as they complete independently

```
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s

real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
```

I tried many things like coupling the commands and then timing , creating a function for two commands and then time them and many other things but every time something caused an issue or didn't give me the desired results. I am guessing this should be an easy task for someone who has some experience in bash scripting.Thanks for your time

Update:
where my_command is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_VIDEO_FILE -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -vf "scale=-2:360,subtitles='dynamic_subtitle.ass':force_style='FontName=Aaargh/Aaargh.ttf,PrimaryColour=&H664c4c4c"  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls s3_temp/$PROJECT_ID/videos/$VIDEO_ID/$VIDEO_ID"_360_.m3u8"
```

Comment: 1) Are these `my_command`s backgrounded in this script, by `my_command &`, or do they spawn detached processes themselves?  2) I presume not, but: can you modify them -- are they your code?

Comment: @zdim yes I have a bash script which has all these the my_command (detail in updated question) running couple of times -(I think u call it in the background, not sure though -multiprocessing i guess) , and I need to know time taken by  each of them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help I was able to find a way around this issue what worked for me is this

```
(time my_commnad1 && echo "output 1" >> my_log_file.log) 2>> my_log_file.log &

(time my_commnad2 && echo "output 2" >> my_log_file.log) 2>> my_log_file.log &

(time my_commnad3 && echo "output 3" >> my_log_file.log) 2>> my_log_file.log &

(time my_commnad4 && echo "output 4" >> my_log_file.log) 2>> my_log_file.log &
wait
```

the output i got was like this were the time is above the tag mentioned:

```
real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
output 1:


real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
output 2:


real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
output 3:


real    2m39.892s
user    8m37.383s
sys 0m3.338s
output 4:
```

Moreover I couldn't test Jacek Zaleski's answer properly though as it gave me some errors with syntax when I tried it in my case.Thanks anyway to everyone for the time and effort. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "output 1:" >> my_log_file.log    
time command1... etc etc
echo "------------------------" >> my_log_file.log
```

This will help as it will allow you to write to your log file and add separators between each 'time' output

Comment: hey SSSDDD, please go through the question again I am running the commands in parallel so they can finish independently which is the issue I am trying to resolve, so in your case how would i know that the output is from command one and not second? . Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(out1="output 1:"; var1=$((time my_command ) 2>&1>/dev/null ); echo -e " $out1 $var1" >>my_log_file.log)  &
 $(out2="output 2:"; var2=$((time my_command ) 2>&1>/dev/null ); echo -e " $out2 $var2" >>my_log_file.log)  &
 $(out3="output 3:"; var3=$((time my_command ) 2>&1>/dev/null ); echo -e " $out3 $var3" >>my_log_file.log)  &
```

...

```
Otput
 output 1:
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
 output 2:
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
....
```

Use in thread variable with proces and  proces name , next I pipeline stdr  by echo to file.

Comment: could you please check the update of my question and describe the format which I should use.

Comment: as I am not sure how will it go with those commas and double commas

Comment: use bracket  (fmpeg ......) example   
$(out1="output 1:"; var1=$((time (cat /var/log/dmesg |wc >test.txt; echo "test2" >> test.txt ) ) 2>&1>/dev/null ); echo -e " $out1 $var1" >>my_log_file.log)